# textField isStretchWithOverflow="true"?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I've activated this property in my textField isStretchWithOverflow="true", and this makes look my report like this; [image]

Now, my question is, How can i do for keek the same height in all fields, regardless of whether or not varies height property of the textField producto.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set "Stretch Type" to "Relative to Band Height" for the other fields in the band.

Comment: Glad to help. (You should accept the answer if the problem is solved.)